# Halo effect with WindowsAPICodePack library

Tags: .net, directx, outline, windows-api-code-pack

Does any one have any experience on how to implement the halo(outline) effect for text with Direct 2D using the WindowdsAPICodePack? I searched for its API with google, but could not find any result for this; so I doubt if it supports it.

I appreciate if you have commends or article I can follow with.

Thanks,
Howard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're talking about DrawThemeTextEx(), DTTOPTS.iGlowSize value.

No, it doesn't.